# How do I run only a child UVM test class inherited from uvm_test?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I want to run the inherited child uvm_test class. The problem is that when you run the `test2` class using `+UVMTESTNAME=test2`, it also runs the `test1` class.

This is because I expect `test2` to be the only one executed except `test1`.

This means that if I implement 1000 inherited test classes and run the 1000th test class, I might run 1000 classes.

Is this the nature of uvm test execution? or do I miss it?

This class `test1`

```
class test1 extends test_base;
  `uvm_component_utils(test1)
   main_ahb_sequence seq;

  function new(string name, uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction
    
  function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.build_phase(phase);
    seq = main_ahb_sequence::type_id::create("seq", this);  
    if(!seq.randomize())
    `uvm_error("rand failed", UVM_LOW)
  endfunction
    
  task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    phase.raise_objection(this);  
    seq.start(ahb0.sequencer);
    phase.drop_objection(this);
  endtask
```

this is `test2` class inherited from `test1`.

```
class test2 extends test1;
  `uvm_component_utils(test2)
   
  function new(string name, uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name, parent);
  endfunction
 
  virtual function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
  super.build_phase(phase);
    factory.print();
  endfunction
 
  task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    super.run_phase(phase);
    phase.raise_objection(this);
    `uvm_info("TEST2", "THIS is run_phase from test2", UVM_LOW);
    phase.drop_objection(this);
  endtask
 
endclass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This means that if I implement 1000 inherited test classes and run the 1000th test class, I might run 1000 classes.

Of course not. Once a test name has been selected, the `run_test()` task calls the factory to **create an instance of the test** with an instance name of `uvm_test_top`. Finally, `run_test()` starts the test by cycling through the simulation phases. Note that all the phases are **virtual**.

> I want to run the inherited child `uvm_test` class. The problem is that when you run the `test2` class using `+UVMTESTNAME=test2`, it also runs the `test1` class.

As mentioned above, we actually only created one `test2` instance. The reason you see the result is because of the inheritance of the class, and calling `super.run_phase(phase);` in the subclass `test2`.

---

###### Supplement: About User-Defined Test and Inheritance refer to the *UVM 1.2 User's Guide*

In common case, the `build_phase()` function of the **base_test** creates the **env**. This fully creates the top-level environment as each sub-component will create their own children components in their respective `build_phase()` functions. All of the definitions in the **base_test** are inherited by any test that derives from the **base_test**. This means any derivative test will not have to build the top-level environment if the test calls `super.build_phase()`. Likewise, the `run_phase()` task behavior can be inherited, as well as all other phases. As you have done, probably the general case will only have the **base_test**, which creates **env**, and the **test1**, which creates **sequence** and really runs the test. But if the current implementation of **test1** does not meet the needs of the extended test, we can write a class **test2** that inherits from **test1**, the `build_phase()` and/or `run_phase()`, as well as any other run-time phase methods may be refined as needed because they are all **virtual**. Since the top-level environment is created by the parent test's `build_phase()` function, and the `run_phase()` task defines the run phase, so the derivative tests can just make minor adjustments. For example, changing the default sequence executed by the agents in the environment.